# What is the mechanism?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

After executing below program, print 5 hello java lines. so i know **i++** is there print 10 lines.I need to what is duty of **i+=2** in this program.

```
 class Example{
      public static void main(String args[]){
            for(int i=0; i<10; i+=2){
            System.out.println("Hello Java");
            }
       }
   }
```

Comment: increments i by 2 each iteration.  Print out i and you will see.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html, --- Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; // i is an variable integer, which is 0 from the start
    i < 10;    // if i is 10 or above, the loop is finished, else the code runs
    i += 2)    // after the code is ran, 2 will be added to the variable i 
{/*...*/}
```